# [UIRoundedRectButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

My program kept terminating due to an uncaught exception. The keyboard works fine until a character is entered on the keyboard.

I have a button to bring up the keyboard and an outlet hooked up to a text field, I'm also the text field delegate.

[code removed]

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `lbl.text=TempTF.text;` is not good in your case. Your `lbl` can be any type of UIView since you just typecast it from subviews. So in your case one of them is a type of UIRoundedRectButton which has no setter for text.

You need to put some `if([lbl isKindOfClass:])` or do a check `if([lbl respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)])`

Comment: Thank you :), that worked, only problem now is the label text isn't showing up.

Comment: Yes, also what @mani said. Actually you have quite a few problems in your code. If you want something to be done the way you are trying you need to loop through all the subviews and do if-else statements for each type of class you want to change. If there is anything outside an if statement it will apply to all subviews so it must be a common method for UIView.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)changeLabelsMethod:(UITextField*)txtField
{
    NSArray *allLabelViews = self.view.subviews;
    for(id subView in allLabelViews) {

        if([allLabelViews isKindOfClass:[LettersOnTileView class]])
        {
            for (int i = 0; allLabelViews.count>0; i++) {
                LettersOnTileView.tag = i;
            if([[allLabelViews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UILabel Class]]){

            UILabel *lbl=[allLabelViews objectAtIndex:i];
            lbl.text=TempTF.text;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Caroline :once try like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have  issue in your code.

Instead of this code.

```
for(id subView in allLabelViews) {

        if([allLabelViews isKindOfClass:[LettersOnTileView class]])
        {
```

You have to try this.

```
for(id subView in allLabelViews) {

        if([subView isKindOfClass:[LettersOnTileView class]])//Here you want to check all subview . 
        {
```

2) I think you have got button object in this line `UILabel *lbl=[allLabelViews objectAtIndex:i];`. That's y it get crashed logged in next line.